# Using AES or RSA for messages with Arduino NFC?

Tags: arduino, aes, rsa, nfc

I'm having a hard time deciding on which encryption to use for the messages send between a NFC-shield on an Arduino and a cellphone. I want to use a fast but safe encryption method and thought that [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) would fit in nicely. The target is a doorlock with [NFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication) as a key. Any thoughts, pros or cons? Is asymmetric encryption better, like [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29)?

I'm having a hard time figuring out one thing with AES though. How is AES protected from eavesdropping or [man-in-the-middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)? Have I understood this correctly: if an AES encrypted string is sent 100 times and someone listens in on that encrypted message, the eavesdropper will get 100 diffrent encrypted strings since AES changes keys all the time?

Comment: This is not directly a programming question, and it is better asked on [security](http://security.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the protocol if you should use symmetric or asymmetric encryption. The choice of algorithm only has to be made once a protocol has been established. The protocol itself depends in turn on the use cases and threat model.

If you don't understand the previous paragraph, you should start by gaining more knowledge. If you don't, you are unable to understand protocols created by others, let alone creating your own protocol. In that case, you are better off choosing a proven, possibly certified off-the-shelf product.

To give you a hint in the right direction, try learning about [key agreement protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) (for example, asymmetric [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)) and [challenge-response protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication).